# Need Hello world example for Tableau chart inside R shiny via javascript API

Tags: javascript, shiny, tableau-api, shinyjs

I'm experimenting to use tableau javascript api inside R shiny. I used shinyjs package to simplify the calls in shiny. The js involved comes from tableau's tutorial page.

After I clicked the 'Call Tableau Viz' button, nothing happened and the browser console shows  Uncaught [object Object] error

(index):7504 Uncaught [object Object]VizImpl$Create @ (index):7504$tableauSoftware_Viz @ (index):4829initializeViz @ (index):8644shinyjs.init @ (index):34(anonymous function) @ (index):33_sendMessagesToHandlers @ shinyapp.js:515(anonymous function) @ shinyapp.js:626_sendMessagesToHandlers @ shinyapp.js:515dispatchMessage @ shinyapp.js:501c.onmessage @ shinyapp.js:114

This should be a very straight forward ones, however I do not know how to fix it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- "shinyjs.init = function(){initializeViz();}"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    includeScript("https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.1.0.js"),
    includeScript("http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/samples/en-us/js_api/tutorial.js"),
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
    actionButton('trigger','Call Tableau Viz'),
    tags$div(id = 'tableauViz')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$trigger, {
      js$init()
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to include the tableau inside shiny ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a small misunderstanding of the shinyjs.init function. It gets called automatically. Calling `js$init()` will not work. If you place a `alert("hello")` call inside the shinyjs.init function, you'll see that it gets called when the app starts.

Comment: Thanks Dean. Tableau js requires the div to be ready before the initialize function (inside tutorial.js) gets called, can you suggest how to make it work here?

Comment: If you need to only include a javascript file AFTER the DOM is ready, then google for "include javascript file dynamically" or "include javascript file from javascript"